# Cherokee+uWSGI+web2py

Tags: python, web2py, cherokee

how i can configure cherokee 1.2 server with uWSGI and web2py? after some googling I read some tutor about configure, but the cherokee version in that tutors are too old. is there any new tutorial or can somebody ste-by-step explain how to deploy web2py app in cherokee?
my system is Ubuntu 12.04, all dependents were installed, uWSGI was installed and cherokee too. my web2py folder located in /var/web2py with config.xml in it for uWSGI params. config.xml content is:

```
<uwsgi>
<pythonpath>/var/web2py/</pythonpath>
<app mountpoint="/">
<script>wsgihandler</script>
</app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a thoroughgoing description of just this type of setup in the book "[web2py Application Development Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/web2py-application-development-recipes-to-master-python-web-framework-cookbook/book)." Here's the config.xml given in the text:

```
 <uwsgi>
      <pythonpath>/var/web2py</pythonpath>
      <module>wsgihandler</module>
      <socket>127.0.0.1:37719</socket>
      <master/>
      <processes>8</processes>
      <memory-report/>
 </uwsgi>
```

After that's in place, you're instructed to run the uWSGI stack as the user who owns the web2py installation:
`$ uWSGI -d config.xml`

According to the recipe provided in the book, you then launch `cherokee-admin` and configure the server via the webui (it should be listening on port 9090). They walk you through the setup of a remote host using the info in your `config.xml` file, creating a virtual host and then giving it a handler. There's also info on using a regex facility to serve static files.